# Write and read a complex object to file in c++

Tags: c++, file, object

I have an object with several vector of other objects as members. I want to write this object to the file all at once(in binary mode), instead of writing each members. How can I do that?
in this case i want to write object "A" from class AccList(all of my data saved in "A"!)
this is my ClassDiagram:
http://askus.ir/ClassDiagram1.png

Comment: Even with the `boost::serialization` methods mentioned below, you will still have to serialize every member of a complex object separately.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

Comment: First time you debug boost::serialization you make a vow not to use it in the future.

Comment: why?So maybe Recommend a better way to backup and restore my data?

Answer (score 4):

you can use boost::serialization for do that

you must add one method at your object

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar,  const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & this->foo & this->bar;
}
```

this method define what member has to be stored

after, for save your object you must do:

```
std::ofstream ofs("filename");
boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
oa << data;
```

for read the object, it's the same way,

```
std::ifstream ifs("filename");
boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
ia >> data;
```

[tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html)

Comment: Can you explain more about it?

Comment: where is the boost namespace?how can i add it to my project?